# couldn't Open assets/sample.xml

Tags: android

I m getting the error "*couldn't Open assets/sample.xml*"

here is my code:

```
try {
            // creates and returns new instance of SAX-implementation:
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

            // create SAX-parser...
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            // .. define our handler:
            SaxHandler handler = new SaxHandler();

            // and parse:
            parser.parse("assets/sample.xml", handler);

        }
```

Comment: You should do it the way that @Michael says to do it but perhaps can I recommended instead using Simple XML. It will mean you do not even have to touch the SAX Parser to get XML into your document. Take a look at my blog post which lets you know how to get it in android: http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Answer (score 2):

Assets are not files. You need to call `Context.getAssets().open("sample.xml")` and pass the resulting InputStream into `parse()`.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to use a SAX parser. Though call getAssets() from an actual context instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling parser.parse("file:///android_asset/sample.xml", handler);